# Calling function of server from view (html page) using ajax, URL is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ionic2, angular2-routing

I am working on an ionic2 application, here is my local PC details-

```
******************************************************
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68

******************************************************
```

I wanted to call a function of server from a view (web page) using AJAX-

**server-page.ts--**

```
public myFunction(param1, param2) {
     code goes here... ;
}
```

**some-page.html**

```
    function onClickMe(param1, param2) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/../../../../app/pages/server/server-page.ts",
        // url: "/../../../app/pages/server/server-page.ts",
        // url: "/../../app/pages/server/server-page.ts",
        // url: "/app/pages/server/server-page.ts",
        // url: "http://localhost:8100/app/pages/server/server-page.ts",
        type: "POST",
        //data: jQuery.param({ firstParam: param1, secondParam : param2}),
        data: 'some data to pass',
        contentType: " charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
          alert(response.status);
        },
        error: function () {
          alert("error page not Found");
        }
      });
    }
```

I have used all commented urls too, I am not sure how to do that.
Whenever I am calling that function, I get error as-

```
http://localhost:8100/app/pages/server/server-page.ts 404 (Not Found)
```

Hours gone, I am stuck out, help me !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: None of your url path seems to match with path in error, Did you try copying the file at path in error?